# Visual Studio Code autocomplete Next.js imports

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, next.js

### Problem

I used to have a Visual Studio Code setup for Next.js and [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)), so that when I typed:

`<Image>` , it would suggest to `import Image from 'next/image'`

This would have shown up in the autocomplete popup which it doesn't:

[image: Autocomplete Screenshot]

### Expected Result

The expected result is that instead of `"import"` it shows `Image                   next/image`

where `next-image` is where the component is being imported from.

The same with autocompleting `<Link>`.

### What I tried:

- Installing some extensions from the "NextJS [sic] Essential Extension Pack"

After nothing I could think of worked, I asked [Copilot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub_Copilot) and Bing for help.
They gave me irrelevant answers, but they suggested restarting the TypeScript server.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> -> typing `typescript` shows me that I apparently don't have anything for TypeScript running

### Information

When I uninstalled some extensions in an effort to declutter, this doesn't work anymore and I can't for the life of me figure out if it was an extension or maybe something else. It won't do auto imports for basic Next.js components or components from '@/components'.

Those are the extensions installed that are relevant to WebDev:

- [ES7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#7th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2016)+ React/[Redux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redux_(JavaScript_library))
- Auto Import [steoates]
- [ESLint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESLint)
- [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) Modules Intellisense
- npm Intellisense
- [Prettier](https://prettier.io/)
- [React Native](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)#React_Native) Tools
- [Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/) IntelliSense

Those are the the results of `npm list`:

```
├── @types/node@20.10.5
├── @types/react-dom@18.2.18
├── @types/react@18.2.46
├── autoprefixer@10.4.16
├── eslint-config-next@14.0.4
├── eslint@8.56.0
├── next@14.0.4
├── postcss@8.4.32
├── react-dom@18.2.0
├── react@18.2.0
├── tailwindcss@3.4.0
└── typescript@5.3.3
```

What is the reason why this no longer works for me and how can I set it up again?

Comment: I don't use extensions to import Modules, fns, types, etc. It just works by default. But sometimes when you install a lib, vscode can't find its declaration file. In that case, you must restart the `tsserver` to autocomplete props from that lib.